# Unable to uninstall apps for secondary account

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, uninstallation, accounts

I have a Nexus 10 on which I have a master account, and a secondary  (restricted) account for my kids.

Recently, one of them got hold of it while it was logged in and installed a bunch of games. I removed them again — or so I thought. I just found out that, while they don't show up in the list of apps tray, they *do* show up among the app permissions for the secondary account, as well as in the list of apps available via settings -> apps.

I can't uninstall them from either location. While I suspect I can I uninstall them from the secondary account, how do I know they're really gone if I do so?

Shouldn't I be able to uninstall them from the master account?

Comment: Not really a dupe to the question, but yes: same cause, so the answer fits both :)

Comment: @Izzy I'm not sure how duplicates are handled _here_, but I'm used to the SF Stack, where duplicates focus on the answers rather than the questions. Also, I'm the OP and that answer solved my problem.

Comment: I was not critisizing you – just left a pointer for those who might wonder. I fully agree with you and marked it duplicate. Sorry for any confusion I might have caused!

Comment: @Izzy, I didn't take it as criticism, so no problem.

Comment: Duplicates are always supposed to be about the question.  I was on SF a couple days ago and saw 5 open questions with the same answer.  But, you're the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings > Application Manager > Downloaded under both accounts and uninstall the app(s).

Comment: Will that indeed uninstall them completely, or just leave them inaccessible for _both_ accounts?

Comment: @SQB It should comoletly remove the apps. If the are getting reinstalled there must be anither issue.